# How to modify wp_nav_menu() html display

Tags: wordpress

Currently when I use

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

HTML Output

```
    <li class="pagenav">Pages<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-116"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=116">Heading 1</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

But I wanted to remove "Pages" text

So I wanted the html output become

```
 <li class="pagenav"><ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-116"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=116">Heading 1</a></li>
        </ul></li>
```

Can someone please help me out.
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short and sweet.

```
<?php
    $menu = wp_nav_menu(array('echo' => false));
    $menu = str_replace('<li class="pagenav">Pages', '<li class="pagenav">', $menu);
?>
```